# What are the data sizes for events and event subscription?

Tags: c#, events, sizeof

Apologies for not quite having the time to try sizeof on an event but in the spirit of enhancing google-fu....

1. What actual memory size will be added to a class instance which has an event field?
2. What actual memory will be used for each subscription to an event?

I assume single pointers for each event or subscription, but I just want to be sure.

Consider this example:

```
public class VertexMovedArgs : EventArgs {
    public Vertex theVert;
}

public class Vertex {
    // what size does this add to each Vertex?
    public event EventHandler<VertexMovedArgs> VertexMovedEvent;
    private Vector3 m_pos;
    public Vector3 pos {
        get { return m_pos; }
        set { 
            if ( value != m_pos ) {
                m_pos = value;
                EventHandler<VertexMovedArgs> tellEveryoneWeMoved = VertexMovedEvent;
                if ( handler != null ) {
                     VertexMovedArgs args = new VertexMovedArgs( this );
                     tellEveryoneWeMoved( this, args );
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Mesh {
    private List<Vertex> m_verts = new List<Vertex>();
    public Vertex AddVert() {
        Vertex vert = new Vertex();
        // what size per-subscription does this add to this Mesh instance (or elsewhere)?
        vert.VertexMovedEvent += onVertexMoved;
        m_verts.Add( vert );
    }
    void onVertexMoved( object sender, VertexMovedArgs args ) {
         // play the vertex like a violin, etc...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An event field is just an object reference.
Until you put a handler (delegate) in it, it will just consume one pointer-size (4 or 8 bytes) per class instance.

Delegate instance have four pointer-size fields, plus the standard CLR object header.

They store:

1. The target to invoke a closed delegate
2. The MethodBase of the function pointed to
3. A function pointer to invoke
4. An auxiliary pointer storing the address of the actual function pointed to (used with open delegates to rearrange parameters)

Multicast delegates (in practice, all normal delegates) add two more:

1. An array of delegates pointed to by the multicast delegate (`null` for single delegates)
2. `_invocationCount` (an `IntPtr`), used in different ways for different kinds of delegates

I'm in the middle of writing a blog post that will explain these fields in greater detail.

Comment: Thanks SLaks, is it then one pointer per-handler added to it after this?

Comment: Ah interesting! this then deems it a pretty bad design choice, in the case of a 3d mesh, to use as per-vertex data or other high volumes of object collections. Great thanks!

Answer (score 0):

An event is a pair of methods, for adding and removing subscriptions (actually, it's a trio of methods, but the third method is generally not used for anything).  Events themselves do not add anything to the size of an object instance, but the add/remove logic will usually have to add at least one field.  The most common default implementation of an event is to create a field of type MultiCastDelegate, and use Delegate.Combine to add subscriptions and Delegate.Remove to remove them.

Comment: In theory, raising the event.  Raising events is almost always done by other means, however.

Comment: That's not a method. That's a delegate field.

Comment: @svick: An event, as defined in .net, is a trio of methods to add, remove, and raise an event.  I believe it was probably defined that way before Microsoft realized that in most cases the method to raise the event should not be exposed at the same access level as the methods to add/remove subscriptions.  Personally, if I had my druthers, an "event" would be a single subscribe method which would return an IDisposable which, when disposed, would unsubscribe.

Comment: No, when you raise an event, you're not calling a method, you're invoking a delegate. For example, method can never be `null`, while event can. And you can't call `GetInvocationList()` on a method, but you call it on a event. And raising an event *doesn't have* the same access level as adding/removing subscriptions. You can raise event directly only from the type that declared it.

Comment: @svick: If you look in the definition of System.Reflection.EventInfo, you will observe that it includes GetAddMethod(), GetRemoveMethod(), and GetRaiseMethod().  VB and C# define and use the "add" method and "remove" method; they neither define nor use the "raise" method.  I don't know any 'normal' .net language which defines or uses the "raise" method, but one could define and use it within CIL if one were so inclined.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that.